# Special Characters in amsmath (specifically in newtheorem)

Tags: accents, amsthm

I'm trying to define: `\newtheorem{defi}{Definició}` but an error keeps showing up:

```
l.24    \clearpage
                 [1] (./Chapters/2a_part.tex
! Argument of \UTFviii@four@octets has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

I've been poking around with what the heck is causing it and it seems that amsthm does not like the accent in `{Definició}`.

Any wonder on why that is? Any of you guys had this problem?

PS: I'm using `inputenc utf8` package

Comment: Is your editor encoding using `utf8`? I can compile a small document (which has not been provided by you by the way;-)) without problems

Comment: it appears that you have a character in the 8bit four byte range, this should not be any European accented character,

Comment: There is nothing in the error message that you quote that suggests that it comes from newtheorem, it is shown as being on a line with `\clearpage` possibly from `\include` ?

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Yes, I'm using `utf8` for every document. I can't share my document, since it's more than a document and that would be a lot of code.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Hmph probably I have a character that's messed up somewhere in my document...

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I'm using `\input` so I don't think that's the case :(

Comment: Okay, I just formatted every document manually to `utf8` and that seems to do the trick. I use Kile as a text editor and this dodgy file format has happened to me already. Which latex editors do you guys use?

Comment: @IgnasiSánchez: It was an wrong encoding issue then. Well, David answered already. And I am using `emacs` of course ;-)

Answer (score 1):

If I save the following as latin1 (iso-8859-1) ie *not* UTF-8

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
Definició
\end{document}
```

Then I get essentially the same error:

```
Runaway argument?
! File ended while scanning use of \UTFviii@four@octets.
<inserted text> 
                \par
```

So make sure that your editor saves all the files in UTF-8, if I re-save the above in UTF-8 then latex runs without error and produces:

[image]